# How can I stop a faucet leak temporarily?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink, cartridge

My kitchen faucet is leaking at the faucet head. I believe it’s a cartridge failure. I’ve got the water shut off to the faucet.

Are there any temporary fixes to get me by until stores are open?

Comment: Are you able to get to the cartridge? Picture of the cartridge and pic of faucet innards? Sometimes taking out and re-assembling gives some temporary relief. Otherwise, using the shutoff is your best bet. Do both hot & cold need to be shutoff or just one?

Comment: If not a bad leak, live with it for a few hours?

Comment: It would be helpful to describe the faucet as best you can -- one handle or two, what do you mean by "faucet head", etc.

Comment: Move the stuff you so charmingly refer to as "her crap" out of the way to some other location until this is fixed. Then you won't have to move it each and every time the sink needs to be turned on.

Answer (score 3):

### Repairs in a Pinch

Sometimes taking out and re-assembling gives some temporary relief, as dirt from the water supply may be caught. Open it up, blow it out, rinse it with a short burst of water by briefly opening the shutoff. Cover the open faucet with a towel to avoid spray.

Otherwise, using the shutoff is your best bet. Depending on the cartridge failure, you may be lucky that only one of both hot & cold need to be shutoff.

Answer (score 2):

Take a piece of PVC pipe (you have one laying around). Slot it so it fits over the shutoff valve handle. Use some tape to attach it to the valve. The length of the PVC pipe should be such that you can turn it from outside of the cabinet.

You just made an extension for the shutoff valve, eliminating the kneeling and bypassing the **crap** under cabinet.

Comment: Works great if it is a 1/4-turn valve positioned reasonably well. Doesn't work at all if it is an old gate valve.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the quickest easy fix I can think of. Let's wait for OP respond.